# How to stop getting e-mail notifications about Jobs messages?

Tags: support, email

I've turned off all the email notification settings under my account's e-mail settings (https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/3826372), yet I recently received a couple of emails about Jobs messages.  Is there some option I've missed somewhere that would stop these email messages being sent to me?

Comment: Did you disable the email notification settings recently? The emails might have already been scheduled if you did it, say, a day or two ago. If it's been longer than that, it seems like a bug, especially if it's been more than a week since you changed your preferences.

Comment: One more thing - do you have any Job alerts? Go to [your setting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/3826372), scroll to the bottom and click "Manage" on "Job Alerts". It's possible you have some set there.

Comment: @VLAZ I haven't changed any email notification settings in a long time, probably years ago. I also don't have any Job Alerts set.